# Kotlin Modules with Gradle Multi-Project

Tags: gradle, kotlin

Kotlin got rid of package level visibility for module level visibility. I think that was a great idea, except it's difficult to get multiple Kotlin modules working in a Gradle multi-project setup.

I'm using Gradle Wrapper 3.1, with Android Studio 2.2 and Kotlin 1.0.4

Here is my structure:

Project

----myapp (android application)

----lib (android library)

----commons (android library)

```
// myapp/build.gradle
dependencies {
    compile project(':lib')
}

// lib/build.gradle
dependencies {
    compile project(':commons')
}
```

When I try to sync or build I get the following error:

> Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':lib'.
>
> Cannot change dependencies of configuration ':lib:default' after it has been included in dependency resolution.

The only thing that has worked is to make sure that the module names have a lexical order that matches the order they need to be built in, which is ridiculous, and not a proper solution.

I know I can publish `lib` and `commons` as artifacts, but I'd really prefer to not do that.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Good question mate :)

Comment: Wierd, I have a multi-module project written in Kotlin without problems, you can take a look at https://github.com/arturogutierrez/Openticator I have an android module, pure kotlin module and a android-library module

Comment: Perhaps you could expand the question a bit with your relevant .gradle files, such as `settings.gradle` and the `build.gradle` files. Only remove what is absolutely not necessary.

Comment: I seem to have lost the branch that it was in (I was working on it a few months ago). Will recreate when I get some free time and update the question.